# How to create password input type in Symfony EasyAdmin 3

Tags: symfony5, easyadmin3

How do I create password input type in Symfony EasyAdmin 3 admin form.
In EasyAdmin 2 I could use `- { property: ..., type: 'password' }`
What is EasyAdmin 3 version of this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use text field and set form type to `PasswordType`

```
yield TextField::new('password')->setFormType(PasswordType::class);
```

Comment: Function setFormTypeOption requires 2 parameters: string $optionName, $optionValue. If I use your example I get an error: "Too few arguments to function EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField::setFormTypeOption(), 1 passed in \src\Controller\Admin\UserCrudController.php on line 24 and exactly 2 expected"

Comment: Sorry, method name is `setFormType`, my mistake.

Comment: How to encrypt it? In this case I got not hashed password.

Comment: @NikitaPushkar You can encrypt it in event subscriber